# Disabling Task Queue Retry in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Is there a way to disable the retry options for tasks that failed?
Its not possible to do this in queue.yaml

```
retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
```

Is there any other option to disable retries?

Comment: I guess you have to fill bug report if it does not work for you, because docs say opposite: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#retry_parameters

Comment: what do you mean with "it's not possible to do"? It does not work or 0 is not allowed (I checked the source and 0 seems allowed to me)?

Comment: This has been accepted as a bug and work started according to http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7423

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If setting task_retry_limit to 0, you can try checking for the [task queue header](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Request_Headers) `X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount`, and aborting if it's non-zero.

Comment: any chance of an example snippet?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version - 1.4.3 it needs to be greater than zero

Trying to upload 0 gives you this...

Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Invalid queue configuration. Task retry limit must be greater than zero.
--- end server output ---

Answer (score 1):

Setting `task_retry_limit` to zero appears to be allowed as of SDK version 1.7.5.

The following `queue.yaml` was accepted:

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 5/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
    task_age_limit: 1s
```

However, it is **not** obeyed.

See also [Google App Engine: task_retry_limit doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505416/google-app-engine-task-retry-limit-doesnt-work)