# Google App Engine: task_retry_limit doesn't work?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a Python GAE app.

I want my tasks to stop running or just retry once if they fail. Right now, they run forever despite what my yaml file is telling them!

Here is a queue.yaml entry:

```
 - name: globalPurchase
   rate: 10/s
   bucket_size: 100
   retry_parameters:
     task_retry_limit: 1
```

If  globalPurchase task fails with a 500 error code, it is retried forever until it succeeds with this message in the logs:

"Task named "task14" on queue "globalPurchase" failed with code 500; will retry in 30 seconds"

Why is task_retry_limit not actually being used?

Comment: Please indent your `code` using four spaces to format it correctly

Comment: Have you actually uploaded the new configuration?

Comment: Check your indentation. Otherwise try with some other task queue

Comment: It doesn't work for any of my task queues. I've tried task_retry_limit and a max amount of time. Both don't work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657605/appengine-runs-failed-tasks-twice-even-if-task-retry-limit-0

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. The documentation and tooling in this area is lacking, but here's what I found:

- The retry parameters have no effect in the development server. I tried lots of different combinations, but it was always just indefinite retries 30s apart. The parameters did take effect when I deployed to the production server.
- I haven't found a way to disable all retries (other than by ensuring that my handler doesn't throw exceptions).

  - If `task_retry_limit=0`, then it still retries.
  - If `task_retry_limit=0` and `task_age_limit` is set, then the queue.yaml is rejected with a message that `task_retry_limit` must be positive.
  - Similarly, it complains if `task_age_limit=0`.
  - If you set `task_retry_limit=1` and `task_age_limit=1s` (apparently the minimum values), you still get one retry.
- The minimum retry time is 20 seconds. If the delay specified by your configuration is les than 20, than it will just wait 20 seconds.
- The time before the first retry is unpredictable; it seems to be randomly delayed by up to a minute. After that, the retries follow the configured schedule.

Comment: > I haven't found a way to disable all retries (other than by ensuring that my handler doesn't throw exceptions).

I just did: 

    taskqueue.add(
        url='/blah',
        queue_name='myq',
        retry_options=TaskRetryOptions(task_retry_limit=0, task_age_limit=1),
        countdown=1,
    )

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, strangely it seems to start working fine after I left it as is for few hours... Perhaps there is some time needed for GAE to refresh??

Anyway, the settings worked for me are:

```
# configure the default queue
- name: default
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    # task will stop retrying ONLY when BOTH LIMITS ARE REACHED
    task_retry_limit: 1
    task_age_limit: 1s
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `task_retry_limit` to be zero if you don't want it retried at all, and you need to use this in combination with `task_age_limit`.  The appengine task queue retry logic uses a combination of `task_try_limit` and `task_age_limit` to determine when to stop retrying.