# Appengine task queue task_retry_limit not working as expected

Tags: google-app-engine

As suggested in: [Google App Engine: task_retry_limit doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505416/google-app-engine-task-retry-limit-doesnt-work) 
I've tried a number of combinations of:

```
 - name: myQueue
   rate: 50/s
   max_concurrent_requests: 50
   retry_parameters:
     task_retry_limit: 1
     task_age_limit: 1s
```

to try and clear a queue but the tasks are being put back in the queue following a 500 error rather than being dropped. Does anyone have a sensible way to resolve this?

Comment: well if you keep adding task faster than 50/s it is reasonable that the queue still growing... I don't understand what is your problem and what are you trying to solve..

Comment: @marcadian modified question to make the issue clearer.